# Looking to find and copy files (with a specific file ext) from a Directory (recurse) using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am looking to Recurse a Folder Structure (ex.F:\Directory\layer1\layer2\layer3) and find all of the files with the specified file extension (ex. ".dll, .txt"). Then I need to copy the listed/found files to a destination folder.

If anyone could send me a good PowerScript that will do this I would much appreciate it.

I have a drive with about 1,000 folders and 5,000 files so this will probably save me a good day or two of manual work.  :)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, modify as needed:

```
$movetopath = "C:\new folder\"
New-Item -Path $movetopath -ItemType Directory -Force
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path F:\ -Recurse
$files | Where-Object {$($_.Extension -eq ".dll") -or $($_.Extension -eq ".txt")} | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_ -Destination $movetopath}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use find command first
then pipe the output of find command to tar.
Untar the archive to the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | where { $_.Extension -eq ".txt" -or $_.Extension -eq ".log" } | Copy-Item -Destination $dest
```

This is propably slower then robocopy. Also, next time please show some effort and ask a question rather then a full solution. This is not a webshop.